# Designing inventory management database?

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures, inventory-management

I am designing data base for inventory management system which is used by nearly 10 to 15 companies. This database contains nearly 25 tables.

Is it reliable to use a shared schema architecture, with each schema corresponding to a company and all schemas in a single database?

Comment: Should probably post this at dba.stackexchange  Fro instance, see this question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8511/over-use-correct-use-of-schemas

Comment: Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question about how/where you are 1st stuck designing. This is way too vague & general. PS What does "reliable" mean here? PS Yes or no questions are seldom useful & (since they ask for a yes or a no) are seldom asking for what the asker actually wants answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read your question, you are suggesting that each company has its own schema. This means two things:

1. If you decide to implement a basic change in the schema (ie not a change that one company requests), then you will have to implement this change in all the schemae.
2. You will probably have to implement different logic in your front
   end program for each company.

Better you should develop one schema for the entire database; each table would have a field called 'CompanyID' which naturally would define to which company each row belongs. This field would be a foreign key to the Companies table.